# Copying the value from one row in a Dataframe to all other related rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe called *data* with potentially multiple rows. There is an ID column called a1 in *data* that is 10-digit long. A group of rows are related if the first 7 digits of a1 are the same. Using info within the row and some more from another Dataframe, there is a way to calculate a Flag for these related rows.

Flag can only be a 0 or 1.

When that Flag value of 1 is calculated for a given set of (related) rows, all other related rows are to have their respective Flag value of zero.

Finally, and this is the part where I am struggling, once all of that is done, I need to copy the a1 value of the row containing the Flag value of 1 to the a1 values of all the rest of the related rows i.e. the rows that have Flag value of 0 should be updated such that each of those rows have the same a1-value as the a1-value in the row with the Flag equal to 1

As an example -

Initial 'data' df (for simplicity, I have only 2 rows in this dataframe) -

`a0 a1      a2  .......` 
`88554  6667778892  12  .......`
`88554  6667778895  2   .......`

'data' after flag calculation -

`a0 a1      a2  .......     flag`
`88554  6667778892  12  .......     1`
`88554  6667778895  2   .......     0`

The above seems to work ok by coding this below -

```
data['flag'] = data.sort_values(relevant_columns, ascending = [True, True, False, False, False, False]).groupby(["a1_f7"])["Rank"].cumsum()

data['flag'] = np.where(data['flag'] == 1, 1, 0)
```

And now, the Final step that is needed to copy the a1 value of the row that has the Flag=1 to all other rows' a1 values and it's not working right-

`a0 a1      a2  ....... flag`
`88554   6667778892 12  ....... 1`
`88554`   **`6667778892`** `2   ....... 0`

This is what I have tried -

`row_with_flag_record = data.loc[data['flag'] == 1]`
`data['a1'] = row_with_flag_record['a1'].astype(str)`

What I'm getting is a Null value instead of 6667778892 below in the second row -

`a0 a1      a2  ....... flag`
`88554  6667778892  12  ....... 1`
`88554`  **`NaN`**     `2   ....... 0`

Comment: IIUC, I think you want to do this `df['a1'] = df.groupby(df['a1'].astype(str).str[:7])['a1'].transform('first')`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NaN values because the mask `row_with_flag_record` skips all rows with `flag == 0`.

The simplest method I can think of -- but there must be simpler ways! -- is as follows. You need a way to map the prefixes of `a1` to the `a1` value that has the flag set. So, you can use a dict:

```
g2a = dict((str(k)[:7], k) for k in df.loc[df.flag == 1].a1)
```

Then it's easy:

```
df.a1 = df.a1.apply(lambda s: g2a[str(s)[:7]])
```

The method that @Scott-Boston gave would also work:

```
df['a1'] = df.groupby(df['a1'].astype(str).str[:7])['a1'].transform('first')
```

but it requires that the df.a1 and flag values are sorted appropriately. So, you get:

```
df.a1 = df.sort_values("flag", ascending=False).groupby(df.a1.astype(str).str[:7])['a1'].transform('first')
```